# hardcode first column of csv file then import google analytics using Python

Tags: python, csv, google-analytics

Is there a way to hard code the first column of a csv file then import my data from google analytics starting at the second column?

My problem is that when I hardcode the first column then upload my data, my Google analytics data is printing on the 1st column instead of the second column of the csv file.

[image: csv file]

```
def print_csv_file(results):
 with open("Google Analytics.csv", "wt") as csvfile:
    if results.get('rows', []):
        # do headers into output_row
        csvfile.write('Site \n')
        for i in range(5):
                        csvfile.write('siteName') 
                        csvfile.write('\n')      
        output_row = ""

        for header in results.get('columnHeaders'):
            output_row += '"' + header.get('name') + '"' + ','

        csvfile.write(output_row + '\n')

        # do cells into output_row
        for row in results.get('rows'):
            output_row = ""
            counter = 1
            for cell in row:
                if cell.isdigit():
                    output_row += cell +','
                else:
                    try:
                        float(cell)
                        output_row+= cell +','
                    except ValueError:
                        output_row += '"' + cell + '"'+','
                counter +=1
            csvfile.write(output_row + '\n')
    else:
        csvfile.write('No Results Found')


def print_top_pages(service, start_date, end_date):
# Print out informat in that's queried.
query = service.data().ga().get(
    ids = GA_SITE_CODE,
    start_date = start_date,
    end_date = end_date,
    dimensions = 'ga:year,ga:pagePath',
    metrics = 'ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:avgTimeOnPage,ga:entrances,ga:bounceRate,ga:exitRate',
    sort = '-ga:pageviews',
    start_index = 1,
    max_results = 10000).execute()
print_csv_file(query)
```

Comment: Please show sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with CSV data, you should use the `csv` library, which simplify both reading and writing. Since your question is not very clear, I can only guess what you are trying to do. For that, please take a look at this rewrite of your code:

```
import csv

def print_csv_file(results):
    with open('Google Analytics.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)

        if 'rows' not in results:
            writer.writerow(['No Results Found'])
            return

        header = ['Site'] + [cell['name'] for cell in results['columnHeaders']]
        writer.writerow(header)

        for row in results['rows']:
            row.insert(0, 'SiteName')
            writer.writerow(row)
```